# Trying to center a dynamic width jquery menu

Tags: css, jquery, xhtml

I have a menu built with jquery from apycom.com that I am trying to center.
The menu items are from a cms and dynamically created when the page loads. So this means that the menu isn't a fixed width.
I have tried several methods using just css, but without having a width set for the menu, they don't want to work.

I have found some information that leads me to believe that there may be a way to do it with javascript.

Is there is a way to dynamically set the width of the div element around the menu and then set the left and right margins to auto to center the menu?

If there is a better way to accomplish this, I am open to ideas.

Thanks in advance
Bjorn

Here is a sample of what I have thus far.

I have already tried using 'margin: 0 auto;' but without a width setting that doesn't work. Because the menu is created by looping over the menu items available from the cms, I don't know the width of the menu.

I've tried using 'display: inline-block;' as well, and that get's me to a point that the block space the menu takes up is only the width of the menu. Now I just need to be able to center that block. I thought that there might be a way that once the menu has been created and the width is then known that you could then apply the margin settings.

Maybe similar to the way jquery is able to apply and change style settings on the fly.

```
<div class="top_navigation_bar">
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="parent" href="/en/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="parent" href="/en/web-design"><span>Web Design</span></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/en/design-packages"><span>Design Packages</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/en/website-maintenance"><span>Website Maintenance</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/en/redesign-website"><span>Redesign Website</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/en/design-fundamentals"><span>Design Fundamentals</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/en/design-elements"><span>Design Key Elements</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="parent" href="/en/website-business-solutions"><span>Business Solutions</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="parent" href="/en/internet-marketing"><span>Internet Marketing</span></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/en/small-business-marketing"><span>Small Business Marketing</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/en/leveraging-the-internet"><span>Leveraging the Internet</span></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="parent" href="/en/doing-business"><span>About Us</span></a>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/en/about"><span>Design Team</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="parent" href="/en/blog"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="parent" href="/en/contact-us"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="/en/faq"><span>FAQ</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
.top_navigation_bar {
    height: 46px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    background-color: #3a8658;
}

div#menu {
    height: 46px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    background: url(/site_media/template_images/images/left.png) no-repeat;
    _background: url(/site_media/template_images/images/left.gif) no-repeat;
    width:auto;
}

div#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @bmeyer71 You could have commented on my answer, so I got notified before. Just a tip for you getting faster answers. Check my edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to center the `#menu` inside the `.top_navigation_bar` then you could use the `margin:0 auto` and additionally use jQuery like this

```
$(function(){
    $menu = $('#menu');

    $menu.width(
        $('.menu').outerWidth() +
        $menu.outerWidth() - $menu.width()
    );
    // added the following line, because the lavalamp plugin
    // corrects itself when the window resizes..
    // so we trigger a resize event, and the plugin fixes everything ;)
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

this will resize the `#menu` according to its contents, and will become centered because of the auto margin we set in css.

example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/MCnbr/

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I have tested it on my menu and it works, with one slight problem. There is a slider that moves to hover over the menu item that you are hovering over. At start up, it stays at the far left where the menu was first placed. Here is a link to the menu I am working with, so you can see what I mean by slider. http://apycom.com/menus/12-steel-blue.html

Comment: Are you meaning the order the js files are specified in the code? I've added the code you provided after the entries to load the jquery scripts. I also noticed an entry which controls this slider seems to be added at the end of the menu which sets it's initial location with a left setting.

Comment: @bmeyer, i hoped that you would call some method to initialize the menus, try putting our script right after the link to jquery..

Comment: Yes. It was the ordering of the links to the jquery scripts. They have a specialized menu.js, that when I put it after the code you presented resolved the issue. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @bmeyer, after messing a bit with the code i have update the code in my answer (*with an additional line*) that fixes the issue regardless of where the script is put (*we trigger a resize, and it fixes itself*)

Comment: That is excellent. Again thank you very much. Guess I better start to dig into the jquery books and get up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

Without a sample makes harder to see what exactly is happening. It would be nice if you post a sample for HTML and CSS you are using. But going blind...

For horizontal centering an element with CSS, you can do:

```
element {margin: 0px auto;}
```

This is enough to correctly center an element.

Note that [block elements](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/) (like div, ul, li and p) tends to fill 100% horizontally. Floating elements or absolute positioning them makes they loose this fullfillment characterist. If this is the case, the elements will wrap to minimum comfortable size that allows the content to be displayed, unless you set width and/or overflow properties.

If you set width, and content is larger than the declared width, it will or overflow, or wrap. You have CSS properties to handle those cases too.

I recommend doind this with CSS, because makes layout more accessible. But if you prefer, you can code width with javascript or jquery, making your life a bit easier.

To process that with javascript, you'll need something like:

```
myMenuElement.style.width = "200px";
```

with Jquery ([width method](http://api.jquery.com/width/)):

```
$('#myMenuElement').width(200);
```

Cheers.

EDIT

Not sure what is exactly the desired effect, but I made a few changes in your css. Check.

```
.top_navigation_bar {
    height: 46px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    background-color: #3a8658;
}

div#menu {
    height: 46px;
    padding-left: 24px;
}

div#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.menu>li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

ul.menu>li>div {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
}

ul.menu span {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Follow [a good reference from both, vertical and horizontal menus](http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/examples/menu/) (I've learned from those).

Comment: My appologies. I thought you would be notified of updates automatically.